# Возможности реализации в Ajax и NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ajax, javascript

Доброе время суток, подскажите возможно-ли реализовать такую штуку с ajax и nodejs.
Может-ли Ajax держать сессию с nodejs и получать от него новые данные? 
Пример node следит по imap за новыми сообщениями и когда появляются новое передаёт сообщение о поступление в сессию, да самое главное пользователь сидит на сторонним ресурсе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax не предназначен для этих целей. Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону long-pooling или web-sockets. Из готовых решений для node.js могу назвать [sockets.io](http://socket.io/), но вообще поиск по "long-pooling nodejs" выдает много статей на эту тему

Comment: polling, "длительный опрос"

Comment: действительно, спасибо :)